# RESTClient 3.5 WizTools, POST method, new data set

Tags: java, rest, http, http-post, rest-client

I am using WizTools.org RESTClient 3.5 for a school project. 
I already wrote some HTTP methods. GET and DELETE work well. I also wrote a POST and a PUT, but don't know how to execute them with the restclient. I tried to insert a JSON data set as String Body but it says 415 (Unsupported Media Type). Is this how you insert a new data set? How do I do it?

Thanks for the help!

```
17:39:40,520 WARN  [org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler] failed to execute: javax.ws.rs.NotSupportedException: Cannot consume content type
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.registry.SegmentNode.match(SegmentNode.java:380)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.registry.SegmentNode.match(SegmentNode.java:114)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.registry.RootNode.match(RootNode.java:43)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.registry.RootClassNode.match(RootClassNode.java:48)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodRegistry.getResourceInvoker(ResourceMethodRegistry.java:444)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.getInvoker(SynchronousDispatcher.java:234)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:171)
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:220)
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:56)
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:51)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:86)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:130)
at org.jboss.weld.probe.ProbeFilter$FilterAction.proceed(ProbeFilter.java:309)
at org.jboss.weld.probe.ProbeFilter$FilterAction.proceed(ProbeFilter.java:292)
at org.jboss.weld.probe.InvocationMonitor$Action.perform(InvocationMonitor.java:155)
at org.jboss.weld.probe.ProbeFilter$FilterAction.doFilter(ProbeFilter.java:318)
at org.jboss.weld.probe.ProbeFilter.embedInfoSnippet(ProbeFilter.java:172)
at org.jboss.weld.probe.ProbeFilter.doFilter(ProbeFilter.java:160)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:85)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:72)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:282)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:261)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:80)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:172)
at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:199)
at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:778)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

here is my POST-method:

```
@POST
@Consumes({ APPLICATION_JSON, APPLICATION_XML, TEXT_XML })
@Produces
public Response createArtikel(@Valid Artikel artikel, @Context UriInfo uriInfo) {
    artikel.setId(KEINE_ID);

    final Artikel result = artikelBroker.createArtikel(artikel);
    if (LOGGER.isLoggable(FINEST)) {
        LOGGER.finest(result.toString());
    }

    return Response.created(getUriArtikel(result, uriInfo))
                   .build();
}
```

and here the createArtikel method:

```
public Artikel createArtikel(Artikel artikel) {
    if (artikel == null) {
        return null;
    }

    em.persist(artikel);
    return artikel;     
}
```

Comment: How did you exposed rest and how are you consuming it? Any code?

Comment: I edited the question

Comment: You need to specify what your post request is going to produce the output.

Comment: Sorry, if I don't understand, I'm a beginner in programming..

Comment: That's json that you are producing so you need to specify that with @Produces annotation.

Comment: Ahhh, so simple. Just changed the restclient from text/plain to application/json. It's working now :) Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to explicitely say that your service is producing json, so just supply `APPLICATION_JSON` in `@Produces` annotation.